# Angular testing: Is it possible to stub service provided by imported module

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-test

I am testing Angular component, which uses member of another module (it is decorator). That is why I need to import another module while creating DynamicTestModule. The imported module provides service, which I would like to stub. Is it possible using Angular Testing utilities? Or maybe can I stub the whole imported module and ensure stubbed members of it? Could you give me such an example?

Here goes my testing module definition:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [TranslationModule],
  declarations: [SomeComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy },
    { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: ActivatedRouteStub },
    { provide: SomeService, useValue: {} },
    { provide: ToastrService, useValue: {} }
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are refering to "Someservice" you add following on the top of code:

`class SomeserviceStub { // stubbed code }`

and change in your provider array:

`{ provide: Someservice, useClass: SomeserviceStub }`

Comment: Okay, thanks, but man, I'm trying to override module, not stub service.

Comment: Is it the translation module, with the service injected in one of the services or components?

Comment: Yes. TranslationsModule provides service I'd like to get rid of.

Comment: The you just need to remove the import of the module and replace it with a stub just as the given example, presuming it's just one dependency you want to stub